# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scripts.trio_ircproxy'

Tags: python-3.x

I just started getting this error:

`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

My directory structure us:

`~/Documents/trio_ircproxy/scripts/trio_ircproxy/system_data.py`

and I am running the interpreter from ~/Documents/trio_ircproxy/

```
(base) ashburry@ashburry-ThinkCentre-M92P:~/Documents/trio_ircproxy$ python3 trio_ircproxy.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trio_ircproxy.py", line 35, in <module>
    from scripts.trio_ircproxy.system_data import SystemData as system_data
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scripts.trio_ircproxy'
```

SystemData is a class I am trying to import.
I was not getting this error before so I do not know what the problem is. Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by putting an `__init__.py` file in the /scripts/ and /scripts/trio_ircproxy/ directories. The file is blank as I am not sure what to put in the `__init__.py` file.